# pandas pd.to_datetime() with format argument not giving 12-hour clock with AM/PM

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, string-to-datetime

I'm using `pd.to_datetime()` with `format=` argument which speeds up the processing as the function doesn't have to infer the format for each row.

However my `format=` argument isn't working for times with AM/PM:

```
pd.to_datetime('01/10/2017 10:15:17 PM',format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

gives:

> Timestamp('2017-01-10 10:15:17')

The time should have been 22:15:17 since the original time has 'PM'
Is there a bug in my code or is there an issue with the function.

Comment: I've never tried it with AM/PM, but I added `infer_datetime_format=True` to my `pd.to_datetime()` code and it *significantly* decreased processing time on larger data sets.

Comment: See the doc for [strftime formatting strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

You need `%I`(01-12) instead of `%H` (00-23):

```
pd.to_datetime('01/10/2017 10:15:17 PM',format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
​# Timestamp('2017-01-10 22:15:17')
```